# How to set environment variables on server/client?

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

On some workstations (Debian & Ubuntu) and on a server (CentOS) I need environment variables for some scripts and jobs. What I did was altering `~/.profile`:

```
SOMEVARIABLE=/some/custom/path
...
```

Is this common practice? Are there any side effects I need to know about? Or is this solution fine & stable? Especially on the server I need this to work reliably.

I used `~/.profile` because the scripts are always executed via job-specific users without sudo rights - so I thought user-specific environment variables would be appropriate?!

**EDIT**:

Since the paths differ on the machines and we're talking about more than one or two variables passing the variables as parameters to the scripts wouldn't be a nice solution and hardcoding them into the scrips would require me to update it manually for every machine. That's why I wanted environment variables.

Comment: Why not setting those variables directly in the script or giving the parameters as command line options?

Comment: Because the paths they model are different on some of the workstations and especially on the server. So I want to read the variables in the script - otherwise I would have to manually put them in the scripts each time I have to change something (for every machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do so, and I use it to change the default of some programs (usually in form of my default parameters).

For scripts I write I prefer to put the configuration in a separate file `~/.my_program_x.conf` and do a `. ~/.my_program_x.conf`.

In general (AFAIK) scripts prefer to have a configuration file for such cases.

**Note:** I think you should prefix the variables with `export`, or some scripts could not see the variable.